# how to authenticate the user using rails api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api

I want to develop a simple api that will be used by iPhone. I have to begin with authentication process i.e., in phone the user has to enter the username and password and then the api has to check if it is a valid user and write a success message else a failure message has to be sent. So how can i do this?

I have looked for example but i could not find a good tutorial from scratch. So please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use devise gem
implementation details can be found at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 2):

If you want just authentication, rails 3 introduced a has_secure_password method.

To your gemfile
        gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

This gem encrypts your passwords.

Your DB should have password_digest column instead of password. Create migrations accordingly.

The has_secure_password adds methods such as authenticate. ie you can use:

```
user.authenticate("secret_password")
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods/has_secure_password

Answer (score 0):

Watch this RailsCast, it will give you a lot of insight on authentication.
So you should resort to basic auth with username and pw

http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api